# How to set text overflow properties in tailwind for 2 divs?

Tags: tailwind-css, react-typescript

I am trying to truncate text when viewed on smaller screens(responsive), but unable to achieve so using `truncate` or `text-ellipsis`.

```
<div class="max-w-xs truncate font-bold">{EmployeeName},</div>
<div class="truncate font-normal">{LocationName}</div>
```

I have tried by setting `overflow-hidden` and setting width `w-40` or `max-w-xs` but still cannot get it to work

Full Code:

```
<div class="bg-black text-white">
  <div class="container mx-auto px-6 py-3">
    <div class="container mx-auto flow-root items-center justify-between">
      <div class="float-left mb-1 flex text-3xl">
        <div class="max-w-xs truncate font-bold">{EmployeeName},</div> <!----------------- HERE-->
        <div class="truncate font-normal">{LocationName}</div><!-------------------------- HERE-->
      </div>
      <button class="mx-3 mt-1 min-w-[5rem] rounded-lg bg-green-400 px-1 py-1.5 text-center text-xs text-yellow-50">Details</button>
      <div class="float-right py-2">
        <div class="flex flex-col items-end">
          <div class="flex flex-row">
            <button class="mx-2 h-6 w-6">Info</button>
            <select id="timerange" class="block w-full text-black">
              <option selected>Choose timerange</option>
              <option value="sixm">6 months</option>
              <option value="twelvem">12 months</option>
              <option value="twentyfourm">24 months</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can play with full code here:
[Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/5mb9wu8Bxq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider setting the maximum width of the parent element of the names such that it will not overflow via `max-width: 100%` via `max-w-full`.

Then, apply `min-width: 0` to the name elements so that this overrides the implicit `min-width: min-content` on horizontal flex layout child items, so that they can shrink below the word lengths:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div class="bg-black text-white">
  <div class="container mx-auto px-6 py-3">
    <div class="container mx-auto flow-root items-center justify-between">
      <div class="float-left mb-1 flex text-3xl max-w-full">
        <div class="truncate font-bold min-w-0">LongLongLongLongEmployeeName,</div><!----------------- HERE-->
        <div class="truncate font-normal min-w-0">LongLongLongLongLocationName</div><!----------------- HERE-->
      </div>
      <button class="mx-3 mt-1 min-w-[5rem] rounded-lg bg-blue-400 px-1 py-1.5 text-center text-xs text-yellow-50">Details</button>
      <div class="float-right py-2">
        <div class="flex flex-col items-end">
          <div class="flex flex-row">
            <button class="mx-2 h-6 w-6">Info</button>
            <select id="timerange" class="block w-full text-black">
              <option selected>Choose timerange</option>
              <option value="sixm">6 months</option>
              <option value="twelvem">12 months</option>
              <option value="twentyfourm">24 months</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `tailwindcss` `line-clamp` classes. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/line-clamp

simple example;

```
// file.jsx

const Component = () => {
  return (
    <div className='line-clamp-1 max-w-xl mx-auto'>Text here<div>
  )
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Note that line-clamp does not work properly in Safari. Might want to take care of that..